# How to write a file to a Internal Storage in xamarin forms which can be found by the user

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've been struggling to write a file to the internal storage. I want to save the file to such a location where the user can see it and read the file such as Mydocuments or in the Internal storage by creating a seperate folder for my app like whatsapp does. I also want the same scenario in iOS.

How do i do that? I have tried the FileSystem Helpers in Xamarin.Essentials and have also used the Environment.SpecialFolder but nothing seems to work. I am just trying to save a simple text file.

The links that I have tried..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

NOTE: I am not interested in the External storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who are searching for the answer. Please visit this link => https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777656/9048996

Here there is solution which helps to create a seperate directory in our internal storage or external if available. Then you can create your own files in that dedicated directory and the files are public and is visible to the user so that they can share them if required. The provided solution is only for android.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to store the data in these folders?

[image]

If so, for android, I make a dependenceService to achieve it.

For example, I want to write a `.txt` file to `Download` folder. I create intferface in PCL.

```
   public interface IWirteService
    {
      void  wirteFile(string FileName);
    }
```

Execute it in the pcl Button click event.

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IWirteService>().wirteFile("myfile.txt");
        }
```

Then achieved it in the android platform.

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(WirteFileService))]
namespace XamarinFirebase.Droid
{
    public class WirteFileService:IWirteService
    {
        

        void IWirteService.wirteFile(string FileName)
        {
          
            string text = "GFG is a CS portal.";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
           
            string DownloadsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

            string filePath = Path.Combine(DownloadsPath, FileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add following permission and achieve runtime permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the answer. i'll try this now and come back. Give me 10 minutes pls.

Comment: First got a permission denied issue even after giving permissions in manifest. Solved it by allowing from my device. Then next the file gets saved without any error. but i cannot see it in the downloads directory.

Comment: Anyways I dont want to save in external storage. I am interested in Internal storage

Comment: Wait for serveral minutes, I upload my demo to you

Comment: Sure I am waiting 

Comment: Here is my demo. https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/XamarinFirebase.zip

Comment: No @Leon. I just dropped it. It isnt working. I am still working on the solution. I have found something interesting in the android developer docs to save file in shared storage and have created a different thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773500/how-to-set-file-content-in-intent-action-create-document

Comment: @Thameem Do you grand the runtime permission?

Comment: Yes. I did. But still the runtime permissions are needed for the external storage only and not for internal storage. Can you help me in the new thread. If yes, I'll add xamarin.forms tag in the question..

Comment: Lu Can u post your answer in this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775981/saving-a-file-in-shared-storage-xamarin-forms

Comment: I think i got the desired solution. Thanks for your help. You can check it here..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775981/saving-a-file-in-shared-storage-xamarin-forms/63777656#63777656