# How to set file content in Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android

I am new to android. I was searching how to create a text file and save it to the shared storage so that the user can access them. So I came across this link.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

With this code telling how to create a file in the shared storage with the system picker to save in a custom location. But I cant figure out how to add the file content. By file content I mean that i need to add some content into the text file. Right now its just creating a blank file without any content.

```
private static final int CREATE_FILE = 1;

private void createFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/txt");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "testfile.txt");
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
}
```

Comment: Also post the onActivityResult code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting this intent would just create the file.

You will have to override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

As you are setting startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
if create is successful, you should be getting requestCode == CREATE_FILE in this method.

Here you can open the file and write your content to the file

Comment: The intent is null in OnActivityResult()

Comment: No. Intent data will not be null. And why didnt you tell that before? And i already asked you to post the onActivtyResult code. And "application/txt" is no valid mime type but it does not matter.

Comment: I actually fixed it . thanks. It was just a request code mismatch.