# Xamarin Forms Nlog not saving correctly to documents or download folder when using specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nlog

I am using nlog but on a physical device int the adriod build I have saved the config file as an embeded resource and it pics it up.

But the problem I have is since andriod does not have MyDocuments.

```
fileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}/logs/${shortdate}.log
```

It will not save their it will go the users data directory am trying to investgate an issue from the customers device but instead it saves it to the data files , I cant root a customer device to get it.

I even tried xamrain essentials and it does exact same thing a folder called files under the app. I want the main folders like downloads so I can attach it to an email for the customer to send to me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
    autoReload="true"
    throwExceptions="false"
    internalLogLevel="Off"
    internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="fileTarget"
            fileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}/logs/archive.{#}.log"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            maxArchiveFiles="7"
            concurrentWrites="true"
            keepFileOpen="false">
        <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" delimiter="Tab" quoting="Nothing" withHeader="true">
            <column name="time" layout="${longdate:universalTime=true}" />
            <column name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
            <column name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}" />
            <column name="callsite" layout="${callsite:includeSourcePath=true}" />
            <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
            <column name="stacktrace" layout="${callsite:includeSourcePath=true}" />
            <column name="exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
        </layout>
    </target>
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="fileTarget" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

I am accessing my log in the usual manor with in my classes

```
private static Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

If I use this out of xarmain essnitials this is the result I get as well which is no good to me either.

```
string dirValue = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory.ToString();
```

Result of above gives me

```
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/files"
```

I just want to zip the log then call the mail client to have it for the customer to click send to me.

I don't want to have a customer to root their device please help sometimes xamrains annoys me  simple things are extra but harder stuff no problem.

Comment: this is Android behavior, not Xamarin.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos

Comment: Would it be saver saving nlog to a stream then emailing that way then @Jason do u think is that even possible

Comment: no, that doesn't make sense

Comment: There is a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63775981/saving-a-file-in-shared-storage-xamarin-forms/63777656#63777656) which saves the file to the document folder with the dependency service.