# How to save a PDF file downloaded as byte[] array obtained from a Rest WS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I trying to save a PDF file, previously obtained from a REST WS as byte[] array.

```
byte[] response = await caller.DownloadFile(url); 
string documentPath = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
string fileName = "downloadfile.pdf";
string path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, response);
```

My actual implementation don't shows any errors but when I looking for the file on cache folder, nothing are there, just a empty folder. Also try put the file in `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` and `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` but there are no files in any folder

What I'm missing?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: are you looking on an actual Android device?  Or an emulator?  Android does not grant full access to the file system unless it is rooted - you need to use adb to get the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string documentPath = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
string fileName = "downloadfile.pdf";
string path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
```

the path will like

```
"/data/user/0/packagename/cache/downloadfile.pdf"
```

As you save it to [Internal Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage),you couldn't see the files without root permission,if you want to view it,you could use  `adb` tool (application signed by Android Debug)

```
adb shell
run-as packagename
cd /data/data/packagename
cd cache
ls
```

then you could see the `downloadfile.pdf`

or you could save it to [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows),then you could find it in your device File Manager:

```
//"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/downloadfile.pdf"
string path = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was so useful for me. There is a way to save into download folder?

Comment: @yensei Yes,you could use `Environment.DirectoryDownloads` enum with External storage,but you may use [DependenceService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to do it on android project,refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63741947/10768653.

Comment: I don't have that property on enviroment `Environment.DirectoryDownloads`, Enviroment has SpecialFolder enum but I don't found Download folder on it

Comment: @yensei Did you use the correct namepace of `Environment` ? The path should like `string DownloadsPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);`

Comment: Was that, I didn't notice that I was using System.Enviroment, my bad!